# How to get format from input Date in java?

Tags: java, date

I want to save events in my database. I have date picker on web app so that user can choose Date from list. But via Postman we can add, for example, 31-04-2020 and it will be saved as 01.05.2020.

In save method of controller I want to check if input date is valid. This can be done by

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString);
format.setLenient(false);
format.parse(input);
```

But how can I get the string value of input Date in "format" view to pass it to "formatString"?

I just know that input is like **Mon Nov 02 02:00:00 EET 2020**, but I can't convert it to format one even with this [link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/simpledateformat.html) because of **EET 2020** ending.

Thank you in advance

Comment: what do mean by we can add by postman, i didn't quite understand your question can you please explain more with an example

Comment: I mean that web view of app doesn't allow to ppick date value less than 1 and more that month has itself (i.e. for January we can't pick 32 value of date).but when we add event to DB via postman, we can use '32' value, and this event goes to DB

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use for example `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: No one can tell from the information that you have provided. The request must come into your server program somehow with that format in it, but we don’t know how to get hold of it from there since we don’t know your system or its architecture.